# How to develop http server with libcurl

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I m working with libcurl. It's very good (as client) and I used to open a socket to a server and then send my http packets.

I'm wondering if it's possible to develop http server with the libcurl. the http server will listen on a given port then when it receive a http packet then the http server return a need to a digest authentication.

I made some research in stackoverflow and in the curl website but without result.

Is it possible to do that with libcurl ? and how to do it?

Comment: cURL is a client-side library, it's not suited for developing a server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To repeat what others have said: no, libcurl is not for servers. It is even said in the [curl FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Can_I_write_a_server_with_libcur):

> 5.17 Can I write a server with libcurl?
>
> No. libcurl offers no functions or building blocks to build any kind
>   of internet protocol server. libcurl is only a client-side library.
>   For server libraries, you need to continue your search elsewhere but
>   there exist many good open source ones out there for most protocols
>   you could possibly want a server for. And there are really good
>   stand-alone ones that have been tested and proven for many years.
>   There's no need for you to reinvent them!

Answer (score 4):

You need some HTTP *server* library (since libcurl is only an HTTP *client* librart) I would suggest to use [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) but there are several other HTTP server frameworks ([libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/), [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) & [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) in C++, ....).

[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is a complex protocol, even if coding a server for a tiny subset (like plain `GET` requests, without all the useful features like conditional requests, encoding & compression, etc...) of it is reasonably feasible. Hence I recommend using a full-fledged HTTP server library, and that cannot be a *tiny* library.